# How do functions in Javascript "delay evaluation" when wanting to avoid eager evaluation?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, control-flow

This example is taken out of the book, *Javascript Allonge*.  The topic regards control-flow operators and evaluation of function parameters.

```
const or = (a, b) => a || b

const and = (a, b) => a && b

const even = (n) =>
  or(n === 0, and(n !== 1, even(n - 2)))

even(42)
  //=> Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

Here the book notes that this will lead to infinite recursion.  I believe I understand this part.  Because all parameters will be evaluated, even if the **a** parameter in **or()** is true, the **b** parameter will still be evaluated (when the **or()** function is called under **even()**, that is).  The same holds for **and()**.  The **even(n - 2)** parameter will end up being evaluated over and over with **n** being 2, 0, -2, -4...

As a solution, it says one can pass anonymous functions as parameters.

```
const or = (a, b) => a() || b()

const and = (a, b) => a() && b()

const even = (n) =>
  or(() => n === 0, () => and(() => n !== 1, () => even(n - 2)))

even(7)
  //=> false
```

Now I understand how the code was re-written to work with anonymous functions that contain the original expressions, but I don't get how this "delays evaluation."  Because the anonymous functions are still parameters to the **or()** and **even()** functions, what's to prevent them from evaluating and reaching the same outcome as the previous code?

Comment: Even if you could short-circuit the evaluation, I don't recommend this algorithm for the `even` function. It will be slow as hell for big numbers, and will produce infinite recursion for negative numbers and non-integers. `!(n % 2)` much better.

Comment: The book notes that it sometimes uses impractical examples since it's not relevant to the point it's trying to illustrate (control-flow operators).  But thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because the anonymous functions are still parameters to the or() and even() functions, what's to prevent them from evaluating and reaching the same outcome as the previous code?

The arguments to the `or()`/`and()` calls are indeed evaluated. But it means that the function expression is evaluated (to a function) and then passed to `or`/`and`, not that the function is actually called. It is only called from `a()`/`b()` inside the function, and only when it is actually needed (because of the short-circuiting of the operators) - that's where the recursive call is actually made.

Btw, this concept is also called a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk).

Comment: Via the book, it's confusing to a reader to read about && and || evaluating expressions, to read about all parameters of a function call being evaluated, and then to imagine functions as parameters being evaluated as if they were arguments for && and ||.  Decided to choose this answer because it seems to most clearly and simply note/remind that the functions as parameters, as an expression, will simply be evaluated to the fact that they're functions before they are passed in, nothing more.  Thanks for the wiki link.

Answer (score 1):

In both versions of `even()`, the arguments to the outer call to `or()` have to be evaluated before `or()` is invoked.  Because of that, in the first version:

```
const even = (n) =>
  or(n === 0, and(n !== 1, even(n - 2)))
```

the parameter expressions have to be evaluated, and the second argument will trigger infinite recursion.

In the second version, however, the `or()` and `and()` functions expect to be passed functions that return values, not the values themselves. Thus, until the code makes it inside the implementation of `or()` and `and()`, the functions aren't invoked.  Because the `or()` and `and()` functions are written to take advantage of the JavaScript short-circuit logic operators, there's no infinite recursion.

Thus here:

```
const even = (n) =>
  or(() => n === 0, () => and(() => n !== 1, () => even(n - 2)))
```

it's still the case that the actual parameters to `or()` have to be evaluated, but the parameters are just functions — they say what to do to get a value, but they don't actually do anything until they're called.

Answer (score 1):

The operators `||` and `&&` use [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

> Short-circuit evaluation, minimal evaluation, or McCarthy evaluation
>   denotes the semantics of some Boolean operators in some programming
>   languages in which the second argument is executed or evaluated only
>   if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the
>   expression

For example, if you have `a() || b()` and the call to `a` returns `true`, the function `b` won't be called.

However, with your `or` and `and` functions you can't achieve this behavior, because they are functions, not operators. And the parameters passed to a function are evaluated before calling the function.

Therefore, `or(a(), b())` will call both `a` and `b`, even if the first returns `true`.

Passing functions instead works because functions do not run until you call them. So, instead of comparing the values returned by them, you pass the functions themselves to `or` or `and`, and since those are implemented using the operators `||` or `&&`, the call of the functions will be short-circuit evaluated.